# How can i get all data from server by apollo-server by nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, prisma

I want to get all data like participant, propose, user.

product include propose.
propose include participant.

if i use query, i want to get all data,
test query show only userId, but i want to all information about user
test query show only proposeId, but i want to all information about propose

prisma model

```
model Product {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  prodName String
  prodCode String
  posts    Post[]
  holdings Holding[]
  proposes Propose[]
}
model Propose {
  id           Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  user         User          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId       Int
  product      Product       @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId    Int
  title        String
  content      String
  totalAmt     Int
  participants Participant[]
  createdAt    DateTime      @default(now())
}
model Participant {
  id             Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  user           User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId         Int
  propose        Propose  @relation(fields: [proposeId], references: [id])
  proposeId      Int
  amt            Int
  participatedAt DateTime @default(now())
}
```

type

```
type Participant {
    id: Int!
    user: User
    propose: Propose
    amt: Int
    participatedAt: String
  }
  type seeParticipantResult {
    ok: Boolean!
    participants: [Participant]
    error: String
  }
  type Query {
    seeParticipant: seeParticipantResult
  }
```

Query

```
export default {
  Query: {
    seeParticipant: async (_, __, { loggedInUser }) => {
      try {
        const participants = await client.participant.findMany({
          where: {
            userId: loggedInUser.id,
          },
        });
        return {
          ok: true,
          participants,
        };
      } catch (e) {
        return {
          ok: false,
          error: e,
        };
      }
    },
  },
};
```

test query

```
query Query {
  seeParticipant {
    ok
    participants {
      id
      user {
        username
      }
      propose {
        product {
          prodName
          prodCode
        }
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result

```
  "data": {
    "seeParticipant": {
      "ok": true,
      "participants": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "user": null,
          "propose": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

it doesn't show about propose and user.

Comment: Do you have a resolver for Participant.propose? Your resolver is returning participants, but not any joined relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Prisma does not automatically return `relation` objects with a query. When using GraphQL, you should create separate resolver functions for any relation fields (like `Participant.user` in your GraphQL Schema).

This is what the resolver might look like for `Participant.user`:

```js
  Participant: {
    user: (parent, args, context) => {
      return client.participant.findUnique({where: {id: parent.id}}).user()
    }
  }
```

I'm using the Prisma [fluent API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#fluent-api) to get the connected `user` from a `findUnique` query for a `participant` .

Note that you would need to do something similar for `Propose`.